# How to detect contours touching the border?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm coding a program that can detect inconsistencies in the powderbed of our 3D printers using Python and OpenCV. What I did until now is create a masked image using edge detection, and then perform edge detection again and exclude any contours touching the border. This works well, however I would like to detect contours touching the border as well. I've tried various methods but nothing seems to achieve the result I'm looking for. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418416/how-to-fill-contours-that-touch-the-image-border) seems to have the same question as me and provides an answer but it's coded in C++, which I do not fully understand.

As an example, here is an image with a contour touching the border: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeqhV.png).

And here is the image after performing edge detection: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I71CF.jpg). As you can see the border of the image is included in the contour I'm trying to detect. Note that the border is not always a square but can be any polygon shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Get bounds of white pixels
- Crop input to those bounds to remove the black border
- Threshold the cropped image to isolate the brighter region
- Apply morphology to clean it up
- Get the contour and its bounding box
- Test whether the bounding box touches any of the 4 sides of the cropped image
- Draw the contour bounding box on the input image
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('streak.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold 
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get bounds of white pixels
white = np.where(thresh==255)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = np.min(white[1]), np.min(white[0]), np.max(white[1]), np.max(white[0])
print(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)

# crop the gray image at the bounds
crop = gray[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
hh, ww = crop.shape

# do adaptive thresholding
thresh2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(crop, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 1.1)

# apply morphology
kernel = np.ones((1,7), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# invert
morph = 255 - morph

# get contours (presumably just one) and its bounding box
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)

# draw bounding box on input
bbox = img.copy()
cv2.rectangle(bbox, (x+xmin, y+ymin), (x+xmin+w, y+ymin+h), (0,0,255), 1)

# test if contour touches sides of image
if x == 0 or y == 0 or x+w == ww or y+h == hh:
    print('region touches the sides')
else:
    print('region does not touch the sides')

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('streak_thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('streak_crop.png', crop)
cv2.imwrite('streak_bbox.png', bbox)

# display result
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("crop", crop)
cv2.imshow("thresh2", thresh2)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("bbox", bbox)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded image to find borders:

[image]

Cropped input:

[image]

Morphology cleaned second threshold:

[image]

Bounding box of region contour on the input:

[image]

Message printed:

```
region touches the sides
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to find whether the contour is touching border or not, and it is relatively much more faster:

```
import cv2
from skimage import measure
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,im_bw = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cntrs,_ = cv2.findContours(im_bw, 1, 2)
cntrs = sorted(cntrs, key=cv2.contourArea)

# you can also for loop here to find border touching for each contours
# For now, I am only doing it for single contour

cnt = cntr[-1]   #finding whether the last contour is touching the border or not

im_bw = cv2.fillPoly(im_bw, pts=[cnt], color=(1)) #converting to 0/1 pixel range
cleared = clear_border(im_bw)

if len(np.unique(cleared)) == 1:
  print("Contour is touching the border")
else:
  print("Contour is not touching the border")

# If its True, contour is touching the border else it is not touching
```